# C# - EF SqlQuery and SQL Server "FOR XML PATH"

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, entity-framework

I have this SQL query

```
Select Ident 
From Synchronization.ObjectsToResend
Where SyncTypeId = 36 
FOR XML PATH('')
```

which returns

```
<Ident>8</Ident>
<Ident>9</Ident>
<Ident>10</Ident>
<Ident>11</Ident>
<Ident>12</Ident>
<Ident>13</Ident>
<Ident>14</Ident>
<Ident>16</Ident>
<Ident>17</Ident>
```

I thought that is a single result and I could map this to single string in C#.

```
_context.Database.SqlQuery<string>($@"Select Ident From Synchronization.ObjectsToResend Where SyncTypeId = {id} FOR XML PATH('')");
```

Unfortunately I get an exception

> Sequence contains more than one result

If I add "Top 1" to my query, I get only one Ident so I could iterate through the results. That's not what I want.

Is it possible to return my xml as a one element? Performance is important.

Comment: StringValue = string.Join( ",", ( your_select_that_returns_more_than_one_result ) ) //replace the comma separator with an empty string or environment.newline, whichever suits your desired output.

Comment: You need to fix your sql query to return one value. or you can use Paul way.

Comment: Is it not possible to do this in a simple way in mssql using for xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be you have to add a root node:

```
Select Ident From  
Synchronization.ObjectsToResend
Where SyncTypeId = 36 
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('root');
```

Without a root node your XML could be taken as many independant lines